# On Javascript function invocation

Tags: javascript

Reading through a javascript codebase (html2canvas), I see a block of code that looks like:

```
(0, _Bounds.parseDocumentSize)(ownerDocument)
```

It looks like function invocation, but what is that "0" for.
by the way, any web links to above Syntax?

Comment: @JLRishe, how do you search this kind of question? I really have no idea about how to search it, when has question on some special Language Syntax